# JavaScript : object transformation

Tags: javascript

I would like to turn an object (input) into another one (output).

For example, I got this input object :

```
var input = {
    'person1.name': 'John',
    'person1.address.street': 'main street',
    'person1.address.zipcode': 12345,
    'person2.name': 'Smith',
    'person2.address.street': 'major street',
    'person2.address.zipcode': 12345
}

var output = {
    person1: {
        name: 'John',
        address: {
            street: 'Main Street',
            zipcode: 12345
        }
    },
    person2: {
        name: 'Smith',
        address: {
            street: 'Major Street',
            zipcode: 12345
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to do something like this, but fail to complete :

```
const input= getInputValue();
const output = {};

for (let prop in input) {
  let arr = prop.split('.');
  arr.forEach(el => {
    output[el] = output 
  })
}
```

Comment: Yeah it is "person1.name" instead of person1.name etc...

Comment: You can't the same key for `person1.address.street:`

Comment: yeah it is person1 three times and person2 three times

Comment: take a look [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#set) `_.set` function

Comment: one more thing you fail because `const output` but you intend to change `output` later

Comment: output still references the same instance object, so I can modifiy this object even with "const" as long as output doesn't reference a new object

Comment: @AntonBoarf Yes my fault sorry

Answer (score 2):

If you use lodash, it is very simple.

Reference: [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#set) `_.set` function

```js
var input = {
  'person1.name': 'John',
  'person1.address.street': 'main street',
  'person1.address.zipcode': 12345,
  'person2.name': 'Smith',
  'person2.address.street': 'major street',
  'person2.address.zipcode': 12345
}

var output = {};

for (let prop in input) {
  _.set(output, prop, input[prop]);
}

console.log(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a function for spliting the path to the value and generate new objects for it.

```js
function setValue(object, path, value) {
    var last = path.pop();

    path.reduce((o, k) => o[k] = o[k] || {}, object)[last] = value;
    return object;
}

var input = { 'person1.name': 'John', 'person1.address.street': 'main street', 'person1.address.zipcode': 12345, 'person2.name': 'Smith', 'person2.address.street': 'major street', 'person2.address.zipcode': 12345 },
    output = {};

Object
    .entries(input)
    .forEach(([k, v]) => setValue(output, k.split('.'), v));

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution based on the forEach loop you provided.

It uses a `parent` reference to the object that will store the property :

- if `el` is the last one in array, it adds the property to the parent object
- if it's not, it creates a new object in the tree
- before looping, the `parent` reference is set to the new object created in the tree.

```js
var input = {
    "person1.name": 'John',
    "person1.address.street": 'main street',
    "person1.address.zipcode": 12345,
    "person2.name": 'Smith',
    "person2.address.street": 'major street',
    "person2.address.zipcode": 12345
}

const output = {};

for (let prop in input) {
  let arr = prop.split('.');
  let parent = output;
  arr.forEach((el, index) => {
    
    if (index === arr.length -1) {
      // el is a leaf, time to add the value of the property in the parent 
      parent[el] = input[prop];     
    } else {
      // el is not a leaf, create a node in the tree if it doesn't already exist
      parent[el] = parent[el] || {};
    }
    
    // moving down the tree 
    parent = parent[el];
  })
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This example does what you need without mutating the orignal object**

You could use recursion and work your way through the keys array until you reach the end:

https://jsfiddle.net/5ykbLpav/68/

```
var input = {
    'person1.name': 'John',
    'person1.address.street': 'main street',
    'person1.address.zipcode': 12345,
    'person2.name': 'Smith',
    'person2.address.street': 'major street',
    'person2.address.zipcode': 12346
}

function buildTree(obj, keys, val) {
  let key = keys[0]
  if (keys.length === 1) {
    obj[key] = val
    return obj
  } else {
    let nKeys = keys.slice().splice(1, keys.length)
    // or if you are okay with mutation you could just do --> keys.shift()
    let node = {};
    if (obj[key]) {
        node = obj[key]
    } 
    obj[key] = buildTree(node, nKeys, val)
    return obj
  }
}


function cleanObject(obj) {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    let keys = curr.split('.')
    return buildTree(acc, keys, obj[curr])
  }, {})
}

let cleanObj = cleanObject(input)
console.log(cleanObj)
```